# X11-vnc with Dummy driver - Screen size too small

Tags: xorg, x11-forwarding

I am runnning Ubuntu in a headless mode, and want to display the desktop remotely.  I found a configuration for the X Windows Dummy Driver and used the following:

```
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d# more dummy.conf 
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Unfortunately, I only get a screen resolution of 1360x768, can anyone explain what I am not getting correct?